# Why is the second batch better quality from the first harvest not fit for the Menorah, but the lesser quality first batch from the third is fit?

Tags: mishna, oil, maseches-menachos, menorah--in-temple

In the Mishna (Menachot 8:4), it says that there are three olive harvest for oils, and three qualities for each batch. The first quality from each batch is suitable for the Menorah, and the others could be used for Menachot. Why is the first batch from the third harvest suitable for the Menorah, and the second batch from the first harvest not, even though it is better quality as it teaches in Mishnah 5?

Comment: Kehati explains that they are inferior, but he doesn't explain the question

Comment: If you're basing your question on the _K'hasi_, then you should indicate as much in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though as Mishnah 5 says the second of the first is better quality than the first of the third, nevertheless, the reason why only the first of each batch is suitable for the menorah is because only oil which seeps out by itself from crushed olives is suitable (as it says at the end of Mishnah 5) - this is the first of each batch, and not that which runs out from the olives because they have been weighted down - this is the second batch, and certainly not the third batch which has been ground and weighted down.